# How to add multiple values to a single key

Tags: python-3.x

In my code I have generated two lists, t_fail and p_fail. For these two lists the index number relates both p_fail and t_fail. So for the 100 in t_fail, the 100 in p_fail corresponds to it.

```
t_fail = [100,100,200,300]
p_fail = [100,105,105,110]
```

I want to make a dictionary that has the t_fail values as keys and the p_fail values as the values of the dictionary. But if the same t_fail value repeats itself, I want to be able to append to the corresponding p_fail value to the dictionary key.

for example:

```
dict = {
        100: [100,105]
        200: [105]
        300: [110]
       }
```

I was thinking about using some sort of for loop but other than that, I'm a little lost.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned @Marcus, this is a good use case for defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

t_fail = [100,100,200,300]
p_fail = [100,105,105,110]

d = defaultdict(list)
for t, p in zip(t_fail, p_fail):
    d[t].append(p)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {100: [100, 105], 200: [105], 300: [110]})
```

Two ways to pretty print your dict

First by looping over the items

```
for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
    print(k,v)
```

The second, by unpacking the value and specifying the separator

```
print(*sorted(d.items()), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Is it possible for it to print without the "defaultdict(<class 'list'>," section and have each key value pair on it's own line?

Comment: Is there any way to save the sorted version of the dictionary to a text file? The only way I have been able to save it to a text file is to save the original version

Comment: You can dump it into a json file

Comment: You might want to open a new question for thius :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

> As dictionary is an unordered data type so if you are looking for ordered keys, you can use **OrderedDict** from **collections** module.

```
d = {} # d = dict() 

for key, value in zip(t_fail, p_fail): 
    if key in d: 
        d[key].append(value) 
    else: 
        d[key] = [value]

print(d) # {200: [105], 300: [110], 100: [100, 105]}
```

Pretty printing the dictionary.

```
import json
s = json.dumps(d, indent=4) 
print(s) 

# {
#    "200": [
#     105
#   ],
#     "300": [
#     110
#   ],
#     "100": [
#     100,
#     105
#   ]
# }
```

Comment: This is a good use case for a defaultdict. The example in the documentation shows how it is used with lists: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: Yeah, that is excellent. Thank you. I know it, it is just to use the concept of dictionary instead of using the already implemented feature.

Comment: What's the relevance of OrderedDict here?

Comment: I do not see any use but the problem has o/p with keys in sequence as they appear in the list. So, I thought, user will be looking for keys in order also and that forced me to update.